# How to search between two dates in python using SQL

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

im trying to retrieve data about a site between two dates and im receiving the error message `1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' date >= '2021-05-04' AND date <= '2021-05-07'' at line 1`. Im not sure whether its the SQL and I've tried using `BETWEEN date >= %s AND date <= %s`

Ive included the full section of code below

```py
    def searchindividual():
        screen19 = Tk()
        screen19.geometry("300x250")
        screen19.title("Rooms")
        individualsiteID_info = sitename5_entry.get().strip()
        print(individualsiteID_info)
        date1 = date1_entry.get()
        print(date1)
        date2 = date2_entry.get()
        cursor = cnn.cursor()
        # combine the two SQL statements into one
        sql = "SELECT siteID FROM Sites WHERE siteName = %s"
        cursor.execute(sql, [individualsiteID_info])
        indivsiteID = cursor.fetchall()
        print(indivsiteID[0][0])
        sql2 = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE siteID4_fk = %s, date >= %s AND date <= %s"
        cursor.execute(sql2, [indivsiteID[0][0], date1, date2])
        answers = cursor.fetchall()
        # remove previous result (assume screen13 contains only result)
        for w in screen19.winfo_children():
            w.destroy()
        if rooms:
            for i, row in enumerate(answers):
                answeredquestions = row[0]
                answeredquestionsvals = answeredquestions
                btn = Button(screen19, text=answeredquestions)
                btn.grid(row=i, column=0)
            else:
                Label(screen19, text="No recorded answers found").grid()
```

Comment: Try `"SELECT * FROM questions WHERE siteID4_fk = %s AND date >= %s AND date <= %s"`.  Don't use comma in WHERE clause.

Comment: Or try `"SELECT * FROM questions WHERE siteID4_fk = %s AND date BETWEEN %s and %s"`.

Comment: ah that may have worked, just need to rewrite the if statement as its not outputting the values onto the screen

Comment: Should `if rooms:` be `if answers:` instead?

Comment: Yeah, I've changed it, its printing the answers on the page however its printing them 25 times rather than 5 as the sql selected 5 values. So its printed all 5 values in one column and repeated it 5 times in each individual row. Think its an issue with the i and row.